# Python class constant using class init method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, constants, class-constants

I've made a class which can be compared and sorted inside common data structures.

The thing is that I wanted to make two class constants for the maximum and minimum values that class can take. So I could call this value just importing MyClass and writing

```
obj = MyClass.MY_MAX_CONSTANT
```

The thing is that calling the constructor or **init** method to initialize these constants is not allowed.

In Java this would be declared as static and it would work, but I don't know how can I do a class / static constant in Python using the constructor / init method. Haven't found much googling but some general recipes for constants and suggestions for making properties.

I don't need a mechanism to avoid changing the constant value since I'm definitely not changing it.

My first try was:

```
class MyClass(object):
    MY_MAX_CONSTANT = MyClass(10,10)
    MY_MIN_CONSTANT = MyClass(0,0)

    def __init__(self, param1, param2): # Not the exact signature, but I think this works as an example 
        # We imagine some initialization work here
        self.x = param1
        self.y = param2


    # SORT FUNCTIONS
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        # Implementation already made here

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # Implementation already made here

    def __ne__(self, other):
        # Implementation already made here

    def __ge__(self, other):
        # Implementation already made here

    # And so on...
```

A second try, by using some functions for each constant:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2): # Not the exact signature, but I think this works as an example 
        # We imagine some initialization work here
        self.x = param1
        self.y = param2
        MY_MAX_CONSTANT = None
        MY_MIN_CONSTANT = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_max(self):
        if not MyClass.MY_MAX_CONSTANT:
            MyClass.MY_MAX_CONSTANT = MyClass(10,10)
        return MyClass.MY_MAX_CONSTANT

    @staticmethod
    def get_min(self):
        if not MyClass.MY_MIN_CONSTANT:
            MyClass.MY_MIN_CONSTANT = MyClass(0,0)
        return MyClass.MY_MIN_CONSTANT    

    # SORT FUNCTIONS (I'm not writing them twice for spacing)
```

But I wanted to avoid strange function mechanisms only for making two constants.

I prefer the constant being in the class and not a module because it feels more natural to me, but I'm hearing any advice or suggestion. Can anyone point me a better pythonic solution?

Thanks

Comment: "The thing is that calling the constructor or init method to initialize these constants is not allowed." - who's not allowing it? Your teacher? Python allows it, but you'll have to create the constants once the class actually exists - it doesn't exist yet inside the class statement body.

Comment: Where should I define the constants? The init doesn't look like to me a good place to call itself recursively

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add your constants **after** creating your class, you are allowed to add more class attributes:

```
class MyClass:
    # ...

MyClass.MY_MAX_CONSTANT = MyClass(10, 10)
MyClass.MY_MIN_CONSTANT = MyClass(0, 0)
```

Only when the `class` statement has completed running is the class object available, bound to the name `MyClass`. You can't create instances before this point.

Comment: Thank you. This works. My only doubt now is how the import sentence works when I import the class. It brings from the right module all the things related to MyClass? How does Python know when to stop importing? How do I know? (Until know I thought importing a class only imported the indented content under the declaration)

Comment: Importing will execute all top-level code in your module the first time. The rest is just binding names to the objects; `sys.modules['modulename']` is the central module object and you get names bound to the various specific names you could import from there, or just a reference to the module object itself. So everything will exist in memory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How would one type this using mypy?  I get `"Type[MyClass]" has no attribute "MY_MAX_CONSTANT"`, and I cannot find any way around this.

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica: you can add `MY_MAX_CONSTANT: ClassVar[Self]` to the class body here. `ClassVar` is `from typing import ClassVar`, and if you are using Python 3.11 or newer then `Self` can be imported from the same module, otherwise install `typing_extensions` and import it from that project.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, works like a charm!  (After I upgraded from my distro-default mypy 0.942 to a more current 1.3.0, so that mypy knows about Self, see https://github.com/python/typing_extensions/issues/96.)

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica: yes, v1.x is a marked improvement over the 0.x series releases. And `Self` is so much nicer than having to use `ClassVar["MyClass"]` (a forward reference), especially when subclassing or having to chase down all forward references when trying to rename a class. :-)